# Chrome is crashing / quitting every 15 minutes due to "Management Action"

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I keep getting this notification on my MacOS machine, saying that Chrome is quitting in 15 minutes, and it subsequently does quit and sometimes I lose my work. Anyone know wha this is due to?

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7703009

Answer (score 1):

The icon on that dialog is from Jamf, a tool for organizations managing fleets of Macs and other devices. So you'll need to talk to your organization's Mac sysadmin or IT help desk about why they're using Jamf to force Chrome updates in such an inconvenient and anti-productive way.